# Hosted Solution for Version Control -- with pre-commit hooks?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, pre-commit

Can anyone suggest a hosted solution for SVN, Git, or Mercurial (preferred) that offers the ability to configure certain pre-commit hooks? For example, when JS is committed, I'd like it to pass JSLint. Or if PHP is committed, I'd like it to pass certain coding conventions.

Suggestions?

Comment: Doubtfully. I'd suggest you buy VPS and set up the environment you need.

Comment: For dvcs pre-commit hooks are client side

Comment: For Git, I think what you actually want to use is an `update` hook, which runs when a ref (e.g. branch) is pushed, and can reject the push .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GitHub](https://github.com/) if you decide to use Git.

[Git supports pre-commit hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html)

The commit hooks will simply be configured as part of the project, not on GitHub.

Comment: Git, SVN, and Mercurial all support pre-commit hooks. Are you saying that GitHub is a hosted solution that allow pre-commit hooks to be configured?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie: No, shaheenery (and manojlds in the comment on your question) are saying that in a DVCS like Git or Mercurial, commits take place in local, client repositories, not the central, hosted repository, so the pre-commit hook runs locally, not on the hosting server. Hosting has nothing to do with pre-commit hooks for DVCSes.

Comment: This doesn't help at all if the reason you want hooks is to enforce access control (ie. to prevent some developers from doing "push -f" on the master branch).